# C counter resets unexpectedly

Tags: arrays, c, counter, ansi-c

The code  below is supposed to take the data from the string s and split it into the double array data with white space as a delimiter. The j counter unexpectedly resets when it should increment to terminate the function

The char *s, being passed to the function is

```
0.0000000E00     0.0000000E00       -1.9311798E+03       8.0321814E+02       8.0294336E+02
```

The diagnostic printf function below prints:

```
0.000000 | 1
0.000000 | 2
-1931.179800 | 3
803.218140 | 4
802.943360 | 1
```

It causes the program to crash

```
void split_data(char *s, double *data, int fields) {
  char buff[DATA_MAX];
  int j = 0, i;

  for(; *s; *s++) {
    while(*s == ' ' || *s == '\t') /* trim leading white space */
      *s++;

    i = 0;
    while(!(*s == ' ' || *s == '\t'))
      buff[i++] = *s++;
    buff[i] = 0;

    data[j++] = atof(buff);
    printf("%lf | %d\n", data[j-1], j);

    if(j == fields)
      return;
  }
}
```

Comment: show the complete program, how may elements are there in data array, value of fields. looks like memory issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop:

```
   while(!(*s == ' ' || *s == '\t'))
      buff[i++] = *s++;
```

should also contain a test for the end of the string `s`. For example `while(!(*s == ' ' || *s == '\t') && *s) ...`.

Otherwise, `buff` will continue to be filled with 'noise' until it overflows. And then other variables on the stack will begin to be clobbered, such as `j`. But the behavior is very compiler-dependent.

Comment: I changed it to 
    while(!(*s == ' ' || *s == '\t') && *s) and it worked.

I'm not sure what it has to do with the j variable reseting though

Comment: You probably overflow `buff` with noise, and then clobber `j`.

Comment: The 'noise' is random data in memory. But often this 'random' data is _entirely zeros_, because for security reasons the operating system must blank any memory before it gives it to you. So `j` is overwritten with zeros, and you print `j++` as 1. (And MSVC in debug mode also sets memory to zero.)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably made `buff` too short, and so your program is overrunning the end of the buffer (possibly by just one character). This will cause it to overwrite the next stack variable, which is probably `j`.

Try increasing `DATA_MAX` and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the `fields` is greater than the number of strings in your character array, then the program can crash as your exit condition is based only on comparison of j with `fields`. Can you please try with the following modification in your code?

```
if((j == fields) || (*s == '\0'))
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your second loop:

```
while(!(*s == ' ' || *s == '\t'))
  buff[i++] = *s++;
buff[i] = 0;
```

You keep filling the buffer unless you reach ' ' of '\t' unfortunately the string termination character '\0' is none of them, so you still keep on filling after reaching the end of the string. In case you're lucky the memory you keep reading contains any ' ' '\t' and your loop will come to a stop before your buffer is full.

To solve your problem you should also check for '\0' in your second loop - even better if you do it in the first (just in case there aren't enough values to parse) or add an additional ' ' or '\t' to the end of your string.